# Saber si hay elementos relacionados en una tabla

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando relaciones de uno a muchos en los modelos y quería saber cómo estar seguro de que no hay elementos relacionados en la tabla.

Por ejemplo, ¿cómo puedo buscar que el registro de canción con el id 3 no se encuentre dentro de la tabla géneros musicales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es `doesntHave`:

```
App\Genero::doesntHave('canciones')->get();
```

Sin embargo, si necesitas hacer una consulta específica en la relación canciones, sería algo así:

```
Genero::whereDoesntHave('canciones', function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 3);
})->get();
```

Puedes ver más información, como siempre, en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence